# Derivation of equations using a general waterpipe problem

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Two pipes are fitted to a certain tank to fill water.It takes 15 minutes to fill the tank completely when both pipes are fully opened.The time taken to fill the whole tank by only the small pipe is 16 minutes more than the time taken by to fill the tank by the large pipe only. Find the time taken by each pipe separately to fill the tank completely.

May I know the data to be considered to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be the volume of the tank, $x, x + 16$ be the time taken to fill the tank by the larger and smaller pipe, respectively. Then you have $V/[(V/x) + V/(x+16)] = 15$ by condition. Clearing out $V$ left you a quadratic equation of one variable, solve for the positive solution.